# Send private message with facebook messenger platform

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a mobile web app that needs to provide the ability for a user to share something via messenger to any of their contacts. Unfortunately, facebook decided to stop the send dialog from working on mobile so that's a no go, and their API doesn't seem to provide any means of sending a message.

The only option I can see that MIGHT work is the new messenger platform, however this is aimed at bots which my app is not. Is it still possible to use the messenger platform to send a message on behalf of another user or will this simply not work?

If not, does anyone know of any other way of being able to send a message on behalf of another user?

Comment: No the messenger platform is not for that

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there any other part of the facebook system that allows you to send a message?