# Send private message to 1 or more friends using FB API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a web application that performs an analysis based on the inputs a user enters. I want to allow the user to send this analysis, which will be 2-3 sentences max, to one or more of their Facebook friends through the messenger platform.

At first I thought the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) was the way to go, but it appears I can't pre-populate the *message* field at all ([source](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method:_.27send.27)).

Next I tried integrating the [Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started) but this appears to target businesses that want to connect their site to a Facebook *Page* and setup a chat bot, which seems far too complex for my use case.

Is there anyway I can allow the user to send a private message to one or more of their Facebook friends or is this not possible for a specific reason (e.g. prevent spam, security concerns)?

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041603/send-private-message-with-facebook-messenger-platform) here appears similar to my question.

Comment: you can't, and you are not allowed to prefill the message parameter. you must read the platform policy. there is no way to do what you want, i am afraid.

Comment: You could simply use the Send button/dialog to let them send a link to their friends ... and that link can then present them with whatever info you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this unfortunately. Makes sense, however, as apps could spam people's imessenger if it was possible.

The best alternative is to use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/) component.